# while iterating hashmap i am not getting ConcurrentModification Exception

Tags: java

value pairs  into Hashmap.while iterating that map i am inserting 1 more key value pair at the time i am not getting the Exception. Can any one Help me when **Concurrent Modification** Exception will come.

Mycode:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> hMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        hMap.put("FIRST", "1");
        hMap.put("SECOND", "2");
        hMap.put("THIRD", "3");
        hMap.put("FOURTH", "4");
        hMap.put("FIFTH", "5");
        hMap.put("SIXTH", "6");
        System.out.println("HashMap before iteration : " + hMap);
        Iterator<String> hashMapIterator = hMap.keySet().iterator();
        while (hashMapIterator.hasNext()) {
            String key = hashMapIterator.next();
            if (key.equals("FOURTH")) {
                System.out.println("key = " + key);
                hMap.put("sfsfsfsf2", "dsgfdsg");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("HashMap after iteration : " + hMap);
    }
```

Comment: You aren't guaranteed to get a ConcurrentModificationException. You *might* get one, or it might work, or it might give you wrong results.

Comment: do you try to modify a map while you're iteration it? that's never a good idea, instead try to modify the map after you iterate or break the iteration after you modified the list....

Comment: if you want a CME (Only God knows why??), remove the `if(key.equals("FOURTH")` and try.

Comment: your code is throwing ConcurrentModificationException

Comment: @ Ninad Pingale ya k if i remove i am getting exception. but if i keep if(key.equals("one") at the time also i am getting Exception . if i keep if(key.equals("Fourth") at the time i am not getting exception could u tel me why.

Comment: @user3721476 See my answers' second section for a possible explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The `ConcurrentModificationException` occurs because both the `Iterator` and `Map#put` can modify the `Map` at the same time. To circumvent that, create a temporary storage for your `#put` operations:

```
Map<String, String> tmp = new HashMap<String, String>();
//...
Iterator<String> iter = hMap.keySet().iterator();
while(iter.hasNext()) {
    //...
    tmp.put("asdfasdf", "aasdfasdfas");
}
for (Entry<String, String> ops : tmp.entrySet())
    hMap.put(ops.getKey(), ops.getValue());
```

A simple observation: If `#put` adds a new key while iterating, how should the iterator know that it must possibly "jump back" in its new iteration sequence to get to the newly added key as well?

## Other Maps

My *guess* is that the `ConcurrentModificationException` might not occur if the `key` from `#put` is added to the `entrySet` such that its position (in the `Iterator`) is *after* the currently iterated element, so that the "old" `Iterator` is still consistent with the "new" `entrySet` because it has delivered the elements in the same order a "new" `Iterator` would have. But that's just my guess as to why it may not occur. Coding like this is really bad though, since existing code would depend on the implementation details of `hashCode` of the `key`-Class.

## HashMap

The [implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java) of `HashMap` keeps track of *structural modifications* to the `Map`:

> The number of times this HashMap has been structurally modified Structural modifications are those that change the number of mappings in the HashMap or otherwise modify its internal structure (e.g., rehash). This field is used to make iterators on Collection-views of the HashMap fail-fast. (See ConcurrentModificationException).

And when an `HashIterator` is requested to advance it checks if the `modCount` has changed since its creation. If it has, it throws a `ConcurrentModificationException`. This means it won't be thrown if you only change a value associated to a key, but don't change the keys in any way.

Comment: The question says he is "NOT" getting ConcurrentModificationException ;)

Comment: @SyamS I don't really understand the OP's english quite there but if that's the case his JRE is severely bugged.

Answer (score 0):

You **may** get a `ConcurentModificationException` but there is no garantee. The `Map` (and `HashMap`) [contract](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#keySet%28%29) for the keyset is :

> If the map is modified while an iteration over the set is in progress
>   (except through the iterator's own remove operation), **the results of
>   the iteration are undefined**.

Some implementations **try** to fail fast, but again there is no garantee. The `Hashmap` javadoc even says :

> Note that the fail-fast behavior of an iterator **cannot be guaranteed**
>   as it is, generally speaking, impossible to make any hard guarantees
>   in the presence of unsynchronized concurrent modification. Fail-fast
>   iterators throw ConcurrentModificationException on a best-effort
>   basis. Therefore, it would be wrong to write a program that depended
>   on this exception for its correctness

Comment: FYI `HashMap` is a fail-fast implementation, see its internal `modCount` [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.addEntry%28int%2Cjava.lang.Object%2Cjava.lang.Object%2Cint%29).